# How to implement dragula drag and drop with dynamic add row and column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a HTML Page which we can dynamically add rows and columns using JS. I would like to implement dragula jQuery for dragging both row and column draggable, like other column can draggable to different rows or blank rows. Looking for solution

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-content">

          <div class="header">
            <button class="add-row" onclick="addRow()">Add Row +</button>
            <button class="add-column" onclick="addCol()">Add Column +</button>
          </div>
                 
          <div class="container-box" id="contentBox">
            
          </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

here the `id` contentBox is the container `div` which appending rows and columns

JS

```
var i=0;
var j=0;

let newColNode = null;

function addRow() {    
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'block';
    row.id = "b" + ++i;
    document.getElementById('contentBox').append(row);

    row.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log(newColNode)
        console.log(row)
        if(newColNode != null ) 
        row.appendChild(newColNode);        
        newColNode = null
    });
}
  
// Column Addition

function addCol() {
    const col = document.createElement('div');
    col.className = 'block-inner';
    col.id = "c" + ++j;
    col.textContent = `Column ${j}`;
    newColNode = col;
}
```

in this code, added both add row and add column button function. There is requirement reference url and jsfiddle url which is adding below

Thanks in advance.

Dragula documentation: https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

requirement reference URL: https://codepen.io/gabouh/pen/ZXrMzW

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/unni2003pj/2b68u0ka/5/